# First Year Linear Algebra -Common points of planes through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra

If ax + by + cz = 0 is plane through origin in R3, prove that two planes through the origin share infinite points in common.

I'm not sure how to get this one.

Comment: Hint: Two homogeneous equations in three variables always have a free variable and hence a nontrivial solution.

Comment: @MichaelBurr awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your planes are $\underline{r}\cdot \underline{n}_1=0$ and $\underline{r}\cdot \underline{n}_2=0$

Then $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\underline{r}=\lambda\underline{n}_1\times \underline{n}_2$ satisfy both equations.